# unresolved externals when instantiate a class defined in another project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have two projects A and B. A contains a header/source file which simply defines a class `Child`. 
I first build A, no problem. Then build B and got `error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`. 
Note I can instantiate Child in A without any problem. I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Project A:

```
// Dominate.cpp
#include "Dominate.h"
Child::Child(int x)
{ }

// Dominate.h
class Child 
{
public:
    int val;
    Child(int x);
};
```

Project B:

```
#include "../ConsoleApplication1/Dominate.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Child a = Child(13); // unresolved externals
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, _Dominate.cpp_ is compiled and linked?

Comment: @soon, I first build A, then build B and got error.

Comment: Is _Dominate.cpp_ included in `B` project? Do you know, how build system work?

Comment: @soon, Dominate.cpp is not included in B. Do you have links about the details of build system?

Comment: No, I don't. I don't use MSVS, I just know how does build work in outline.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you need to get dominate.obj linked into project B.  I'm not enough of a VS build expert to give you details on how to do that, though one simple and viable approach might be to add dominate.cpp to project B.  I believe the menu item is something like Project/Add Existing..., then browse and select dominate.cpp.

Comment: Then you probably need to create a .lib file as part of A's build process, and add *that* to B.

Comment: I'd also point out, that, since you're willing to share the same header file, it's unclear why you're reluctant to share the cpp file in both projects.

Comment: maybe because OP wants to build a library and use it. It's still a legitimate desire these days.

Answer (score 0):

Both cpp files need to be in the same project. You can use menu command Project, Add to Project, ... to make it so. Then use the Build command. It compiles both cpp's, then runs the linker to combine the two objs. It is this linker step that you are missing.